# I am trying to figure out 'n to m in steps of p where n, m and p are inputted by the user'

Tags: python

I am new to coding and am trying to figure out how to do this, I have done this so far:

[Image of What I have coded so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhBLW.png)

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to achieve this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following are the ones you are looking for.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements
https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range

Now, the snippet you're trying to code looks like this:

```
n = int(input("First Number: "))
m = int(input("Second Number: "))
p = int(input("Third Number: "))

# Start from n, go until m (includes m), in steps of p
for i in range(n, m + 1, p):
    print(i, end = " ")

print()
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I've been trying to figure this out for a while XD.